# Django Rest Framework model relations

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, models, entity-relationship

I'm creating school project, Gallery app. I have next entities: `Profile`, `Album`, `Image`, `Tag`, `Like`, `Comment`. But i'm a little bit confused with relations. I created all, but i'm not sure everything is good. Please check:

#### Profile:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user            = models.OneToOneField(User)
    albums          = models.ManyToManyField("albums.Album", blank=True)
    commented       = models.ManyToManyField("comments.Comment", blank=True, unique=False)
    liked           = models.ManyToManyField("likes.Like", blank=True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField( blank=True, null=True, upload_to='profile_pics')
    timestamp       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated         = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

#### Album:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, null=False)
    owner       = models.ForeignKey("profiles.Profile")
    description = models.TextField( max_length=500, null=True)
    images      = models.ManyToManyField("images.Image", related_name="album_images", blank=True)
    is_public   = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp   = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated     = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

#### Image

```
class Image(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, null=True)
    album       = models.ForeignKey("albums.Album", related_name="album_id", null=True, blank=True)
    image       = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Image", blank=True, null=True, upload_to='img')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    comments    = models.ManyToManyField("comments.Comment", related_name="all_comments", blank=True, unique=False)
    likes       = models.ManyToManyField("likes.Like", related_name="all_likes", blank=True, unique=False)
    tags        = models.ManyToManyField("tags.Tag", related_name="all_tags", blank=True)
    is_public   = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp   = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated     = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

#### Tags

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name      = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, null=False)
    images    = models.ManyToManyField("images.Image", blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

#### Likes

```
class Like(models.Model):
    owner     = models.ManyToManyField("profiles.Profile")
    image     = models.ManyToManyField("images.Image")
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

#### Comments

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    owner     = models.ManyToManyField("profiles.Profile", unique=False)
    image     = models.ManyToManyField("images.Image", unique=False)
    content   = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=False, null=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

---

How it looks like to you? Am i wrong somewhere?

Comment: do you have a specific question?

Comment: Basically, question is is everything ok? How can it be better?

Comment: your question probably belongs in https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/